# Select with IN, filtering the matched results

Tags: mysql

What I want to perform is:

Select some rows from a table using IN, but while my query matches the rows, I need it to match those which has the latest update_date.

More explanation:

So we have this table

```
id  update_date value   record_id
1   2015-01-01  1       1
2   2015-01-02  2       1
3   2015-01-03  3       1
4   2015-02-02  100     2
5   2015-02-03  101     2
```

so basically my SQL query will be something like this:

```
select * from `table` WHERE `record_id` IN (1,2,3)
```

and it will return exacly 5 rows.

What i need is to return 2 rows like this:

```
id  update_date value   record_id
3   2015-01-03  3       1
5   2015-02-03  101     2
```

If you take a closer look, those are the ones with the latest update date.
I need this in a single query, but I am not quite sure it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Note: some record_ids might be missing

Comment: Pretty sure cant be done in a 'single' query.  You can do a sub query

Comment: It **can** be done in a single query (without subqueries), using a join (`LEFT JOIN`). This question was asked hundreds of times on SO. It even has its own tag: [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the maximum update date for each record in a subquery.  Then `join` the table back to get the rest of the fields:

```
select t.*
from (select record_id, max(update_date) as maxud
      from `table`
      where `record_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
      group by record_id
     ) r join
     `table` t
     on r.record_id = t.record_id and r.maxud = t.update_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT mr.*
FROM `table` mr                     # "mr" from "most recent"
  LEFT JOIN `table` nt              # "nt" from "newer than" (most recent)
      ON mr.record_id = nt.record_id AND mr.update_date < nt.update_date
WHERE mr.record_id IN (1, 2, 3)     # your filter here
  AND nt.record_id IS NULL
```

#### How it works

It joins the table (aliased as `mr`) with itself (aliased as `nt`). The `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the records from `mr` (the table on the left) are present in the joined set. Each row from `mr` is paired will all the rows from `nt` that have the same value on column `record_id` AND are newer (`mr.update_date < nt.update_date`). When no such record is present in `nt` (because the row selected from `mr` is the most recent), the fields from `nt` are filled with `NULL`.

The `WHERE` condition `nt.record_id IS NULL` keeps from the joined set only these records from `mr` that have no pair in `nt` (there is no more recent row in `nt` because the row from `mr` is the most recent).

The other condition on the `WHERE` clause (always put in on the fields of `mt`) does the filtering you wanted in the first place.

Finally, `SELECT` the fields you need from `mr` (because those from `nt` are all `NULL`).